# Is it possible to use a file on External Storage Directory inside android webview?

Tags: android, file, webview, android-external-storage

I have a hybrid app that plays mp3, but I don't want to set all the mp3s inside the assets folder, I want the user to select mp3 that he/she likes to download.

So the question is... Can I use a previously downloaded mp3 inside webview, natively in the app data folder?

Something like this in file:///android_assets/index.html:

```
<html><body>
<audio src="file:///Android/data/com.packagename/previouslydownloaded.mp3">
</body></html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android Lollipop you can use files from anywhere because WebView has gained full support for `content://` scheme. Older Android versions may also work (for example, MediaPlayer gained Uri support for playback in API 14). Just create a ContentProvider and refer to associated content uris directly in web page.

```
<html><body>
<audio src="content://com.example.authority/file/path.mp3">
</body></html>
```

Both files from secondary external storage (accessible only via Storage Access Framework) and your app private files, exposed via FileProvider or something like that, should be accessible via `content://`.

Note, that writing ContentProviders is slightly tricky business, you may want to look at following question and all it's answers: [Is it possible to use content:// as a source for an <audio> element in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578433/1643723)